# Javascript - Find most frequent number in array, even if there are two

Tags: javascript

If I have an array of numbers and I want to get the one that occurs the most frequent, yet there are two possible answers, Im having trouble sorting that part out. For example, below should return 1 and 7 but I only get 7. Any help is appreciated.

```js
let arr = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7];

function findMode(numbers) {
    let counted = numbers.reduce((acc, curr) => { 
        if (curr in acc) {
            acc[curr]++;
        } else {
            acc[curr] = 1;
        }

        return acc;
    }, {});

    let mode = Object.keys(counted).reduce((a, b) => counted[a] > counted[b] ? a : b);

    return mode;
}

console.log(findMode(arr));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could group equal items in sub-arrays, then sort by sub-array length and retrieve the first values with the same array length like this:

```js
const arr = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7],
  output = arr
    .sort((a, b) => a - b)
    .reduce(
      (acc, cur, i, { [i - 1]: last }) =>
        (cur === last ? acc[acc.length - 1].push(cur) : acc.push([cur])) && acc,
      []
    )
    .sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length)
    .reduce(
      (a, b, _, [first]) => (first.length === b.length ? [...a, b[0]] : a),
      []
    );

console.log(output);
```

Comment: This will only work on a sorted input array, i. e. when the repeating elements occur right next to one another. For example, the `9` will not be picked up from `[1, 1, 9, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 6, 7, 7]`.

Comment: Indeed, I added a sort at the beginning

Answer (score 2):

You can use an array as the accumulator.

```js
let arr = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7];

function findMode(numbers) {
    let counted = numbers.reduce((acc, curr) => { 
        if (curr in acc) {
            acc[curr]++;
        } else {
            acc[curr] = 1;
        }

        return acc;
    }, {});

    let mode = Object.keys(counted).reduce((acc, curr) => {
      if(!acc.length || counted[curr] > counted[acc[0]]) return [curr];
      if(counted[curr] === counted[acc[0]]) acc.push(curr);
      return acc;
    }, []);

    return mode;
}
console.log(findMode(arr));
```

Alternatively, you can find the highest frequency and then use `filter` to find numbers with that frequency.

```js
let arr = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7];

function findMode(numbers) {
    let counted = numbers.reduce((acc, curr) => { 
        if (curr in acc) {
            acc[curr]++;
        } else {
            acc[curr] = 1;
        }
        return acc;
    }, {});
    let mode = Math.max(...Object.values(counted));
    return Object.keys(counted).filter(x => counted[x] === mode);
}
console.log(findMode(arr));
```

Comment: By using the numbers as object properties you are converting them to strings

Comment: @GuerricP The original solution also returns a string, so this not appear to be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep track of the `max` number of occurrences in the first loop, and then use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get the `keys` with such value:

```js
function findMode(numbers) {
    let max = 0;
    const counted = numbers.reduce((acc, curr) => { 
        if (curr in acc) acc[curr]++;
        else acc[curr] = 1;
        if(acc[curr] > max) max = acc[curr];
        return acc;
    }, {});
    const mode = Object.keys(counted)
      .filter(key => counted[key] === max)
      .map(Number);
    return mode;
}

console.log( findMode([1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7]) );
```

Comment: By using the numbers as object properties you are converting them to strings

Answer (score 0):

As the whole action is happening within a function scope we can also do it with two `.forEach()` loops: in the first one we collect the counts and in the second one we then assemble a results array with the "winners".

By using a `map` for collecting the counts we avoid the type conversion to string that would have occurred had we used a plain object.

```js
let arr = [1, 1, 2, "1", 3, 4, "1", 5, 6, 7, 7];

function findMode(nums) {
  let cn=new Map(),mx=0,res;
  nums.forEach(n=>cn.set(n,(cn.get(n)||0)+1));
  [...cn.entries()].forEach(([v,c])=>{
   if(c>mx) {res=[v];mx=c}
   else if (c===mx) res.push(v) });
  return res;
}
console.log(findMode(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the array by taking count, max frequency and values directly in a single loop.

```js
function findMode(numbers) {
    return numbers
        .reduce((r, v) => { 
            r[v] = (r[v] || 0) + 1;
            if (r[v] === r.max) r.values.push(v);
            if (r[v] > r.max) {
                r.max = r[v];
                r.values = [v];
            }
            return r;
        }, { max: 0, values: [] })
        .values;
}

console.log(findMode([1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7]));
```